# Error Running i-Code CNES Batch Script for Fortran Analysis: "Unrecognized option"

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use [i-Code CNES](https://github.com/cnescatlab/i-CodeCNES) for static code analysis on Fortran projects. After downloading the CLI tool from the [4.1.2 release](https://github.com/cnescatlab/i-CodeCNES/releases/download/4.1.2/icode-4.1.2.zip) and attempting to run the `icode.bat` script, I encounter the following error:

```
Unrecognized option: -
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I'm not very familiar with debugging cmd-batch scripts, and the error message does not specify the problematic line or option. The batch script is from their GitHub repository, available [here](https://github.com/cnescatlab/i-CodeCNES/blob/5ce536ed06538832089490ec10320ca046c1b83a/icode-app/src/main/scripts/icode.bat#L4).

```bat
@REM i-Code CNES Startup Script for Windows
@REM
@REM Required ENV vars:
@REM   JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir

@echo off

set ERROR_CODE=0

@REM set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
@setlocal

set "scriptdir=%~dp0"
if #%scriptdir:~-1%# == #\# set scriptdir=%scriptdir:~0,-1%
set "ICODE_HOME=%scriptdir%"

@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
@REM *** JAVA EXEC VALIDATION ***

if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto foundJavaHome

for %%i in (java.exe) do set JAVA_EXEC=%%~$PATH:i

if not "%JAVA_EXEC%" == "" (
  set JAVA_EXEC="%JAVA_EXEC%"
  goto OkJava
)

if not "%JAVA_EXEC%" == "" goto OkJava

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment, and no Java
echo        executable present in the PATH.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation, or add "java.exe" to the PATH
echo.
goto error

:foundJavaHome
if EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto foundJavaExeFromJavaHome

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home
echo        folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.
echo.
goto error

:foundJavaExeFromJavaHome
set JAVA_EXEC="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

:OkJava
goto run


@REM ==== START RUN ====
:run

set PROJECT_HOME=%CD%

@REM remove trailing backslash, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/wi7u-CyV_tc/3u9UKRmABQAJ
IF %PROJECT_HOME:~-1% == \ SET PROJECT_HOME=%PROJECT_HOME:~0,-1%

%JAVA_EXEC% -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -cp %ICODE_HOME%\*;%ICODE_HOME%\plugins\* fr.cnes.icode.application.ICodeApplication %*
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end

:error
set ERROR_CODE=1

@REM ==== END EXECUTION ====

:end
@REM set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
@endlocal & set ERROR_CODE=%ERROR_CODE%

@REM see http://code-bear.com/bearlog/2007/06/01/getting-the-exit-code-from-a-batch-file-that-is-run-from-a-python-program/
goto exit

:returncode
exit /B %1

:exit
call :returncode %ERROR_CODE%
```

#### What I've Tried:

- Ensuring that `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly and points to a valid JDK installation.
- Verifying that `java.exe` is accessible from the command line and the correct version is being used.
- Reading through the batch script to identify any obvious syntax issues, especially around JVM options.

The line that seems to be causing the issue involves setting JVM options for memory and classpath:

```bat
%JAVA_EXEC% -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -cp %ICODE_HOME%\*;%ICODE_HOME%\plugins\* fr.cnes.icode.application.ICodeApplication %*
```

I suspect the error might be related to the JVM options, particularly `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`, but I'm not sure.

#### Questions:

1. How can I determine the exact cause of the "Unrecognized option" error in this context?
2. Is there a way to debug cmd-batch scripts to pinpoint where the error occurs?
3. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with i-Code CNES or JVM options in batch scripts and knows how to resolve it?

Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the various options selected one by one
2. On starting a batch, the `echo` state is always `on`, meaning that a logical line will be reported to the console as it will be executed (ie. with substitutions of values for variable-names having been done). A batch line that starts `@` is not `echo`ed before execution.

The command `echo off` (usually `@echo off`) will disable the reporting. `echo on` (`@echo on`) will restart it.

Consequently, the usual start line for a batch is `@echo off`, which obviates the need for further `@` lines.

Since the default mode is `echo on`, the entire batch execution is reported to the console, but any section of the batch can be exposed by simply toggling the `echo` state, so for debugging,

```
@echo off
.....
@echo on
code line being analysed
code line being analysed
code line being analysed
@echo off
....
```

allows the exact instructions to be executed to be shown on the console.

the command line

```
pause
```

will halt execution of the batch so that the report can be read. The batch can then be continued or can be terminated by using Control-C

Usually, this is how a batch file is debugged.

As an aside, the command

```
set xyz
```

reports the values of environment variables whose names start `xyz` which may be of use while debugging.

3. Undoubtedly.

From what I read at [Oracle's Java command-line options page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java) it appears that there is a `-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit` option, but there is no mention of a `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` option, as `-UseGCOverheadLimit` is the default.

I suspect that this may be the root of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. I used your advice by removing the `@echo off` line. Having the output printed out in the terminal, I could find the problem and fix it below. Posted an answer here and also submitted a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running the script from a directory with spaces in its path. So I changed the suspicious line to:

```bat
%JAVA_EXEC% -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -cp "%ICODE_HOME%\*";"%ICODE_HOME%\plugins\*" fr.cnes.icode.application.ICodeApplication %*
```

placing double quotation marks `"` around the paths. I have already sent a [pull request](https://github.com/cnescatlab/i-CodeCNES/pull/234) that I belive will resolve the issue.